# How to use stubsPerConsumer with restdocs

Tags: spring-restdocs, spring-cloud-contract

How do I use the [stubsPerConsumer](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stubs_per_consumer) feature when creating a [stub from a producer with restdocs](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_with_restdocs/src/test/java/com/example/ProducerControllerTests.java#L64)?

If this is not supported, is it possible to generate the asciidoc snippets from the groovy DSL contract?

---

**Update**

It looks like baseClassMappings is not supported when using spring-cloud-contract with restdocs.  Has anyone found a clever way to get this to work using the assembly-plugin (that doesn't require a lot of manual setup for each consumer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not supported on the producer side with rest docs out of the box. We treat rest docs as a way to do the producer contract approach. Theoretically what you could do is to create different output snippet directories. Instead of for example `target/snippets` you could do `target/snippets/myconsumer`. Then with the assembly plugin you would just pick the `target/snippets`. At least that's how theory would work.

As for the contracts and adocs you can check out this: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/beer_contracts/src/test/java/docs/GenerateAdocsFromContractsTests.java . It's a poor man's version of going through all of the contracts and generation of adoc documentation from them.